# ReactJS - IE save dialog fails

Tags: reactjs, internet-explorer

My react app saves files. I am receiving the file in the form of a data URL, then converting it to a blob for the user to save. I get the save dialog to pop up in IE11, however, after hitting 'Save', the browser says it can't be downloaded, then on Retry it gets stuck on 'Resuming...'. Any ideas? Code is below.

```
var mimeType = data.split(',')[0].split(':')[1].split(';')[0]; //data is the dataURL
var extension = mimeType.substr(mimeType.lastIndexOf('/') + 1); //get file extension

var byteString = atob(data.split(',')[1]);
var ab = new ArrayBuffer(byteString.length);
var blob = new Blob([ab], { type: mimeType }); //convert dataURL to blob

window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, fileName + "." + extension);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was an issue the with browser itself. Rolled it back to IE9 then reinstalled IE11 and everything worked fine.